# Highcharts credits to be enabled while printing

Tags: highcharts

Hi all how to enable or disable credits in highcharts while printing with an external print button.
Please let me know how best we can show this ?

Answer (score 1):

The credits are part of your chart, see the [Highcharts API Reference Credits](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits) page

```
credits: {
    text: 'my credits',
    href: 'http://linktomyreference.com'
}
```

By default the credits are enabled, if you want to disable them but not remove them from the script you can use the enabled property:

```
credits: {
    enabled: false,
    text: 'my credits',
    href: 'http://linktomyreference.com'
}
```

In the above example the credits are disabled but remain present in your markup.

To change that you can use `Highcharts.setOptions` like so:

```
var enableCredits = {credits: { enabled: true }};
var disableCredits = {credits: { enabled: false }};

Highcharts.setOptions(disableCredits);
```

Then you just bind the execution of `Highcharts.setOptions(enableCredits);` to your button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use chartOptions for exporting file: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions